# Sequelize.js - add an item to a table, connected to a User in a different table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a `users` and `colors` table. In my example, there is already a user row that exists in the `users` table. I want to be able to add a color (or, connect a color) to that existing user.

This is how the association is set up:

```
db.color.belongsTo(db.user);
db.user.hasMany(db.color);
```

So a user can have many different colors attached to it.

To add a color to a user I've tried the following:

```
db.color.create({
    colorName: 'blue',
    include: [{
        model: db.user,
        where: {
            id: 12454
        }
    }]
})
```

While this adds a new color row to the `colors` table, it doesn't connect it to the given user; it gives this result:

```
{"id":1,"colorName":"blue","userId":null}
```

How do I connect this color to the specified user in the `users` table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following

References: [Sequelize documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/associations/belongs-to.js~BelongsTo.html#instance-method-set)

```
let UserInfo = user.find({
    where: {id: 12454}
});
let addColor = color.create({name: "blue"});

sequelize.Promise.all([UserInfo, addColor]).spread((User, Color)=> {
    return Color.setUser(User);
});
```

> connection.Promise is a bluebird Object which is exposed by Sequelize.

Comment: Your find query needs curly braces like this: `db.user.find({ })`. And even with that, this doesn't work; just returns an error.

Comment: @MonkeyOnARock I have updated the answer. Please check now

Comment: So it will insert the new color to the `color` table... but the `userId` will still be blank... when the `Promise.all` is run, it gives the following error: `Cannot read property 'setUser' of undefined`

Comment: Upon further investigation, it appears that `Color` is returning `undefined`. It appears that `User` (in `Promise.all`) has *both* the user object, as well as the new color object.

Comment: If you are using Promise.all().then(), It gives an array which contains the responses of all the promises. That is why i used Promise.all().spread.

`connection` is the Sequelize connection object.

node.js core Promise library is still not mature enough. That is why I used bluebird object
[link](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/spread.html)

Comment: Well, whether I use `spread` or `then`, I still get an error... the color will be inserted into `color` table, but the `userId` remains null.

Comment: Can you tell me which version of Sequelize are you using?

Comment: Sequelize Version 4.7.5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153209/discussion-between-hemant-kumar-and-monkeyonarock).